# How to use a C++ library method in a visual studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to test a method from a static library that I created. The method from the library just prints something to the console. I have added the directory in the properties tab and added the linker input. However, the project still does not recognise the library. Would anyone be able to help. Any help is appreciated.

**Libary header:**

```
void TestLiabry();
```

**Libary method:**

```
void TestLiabrys()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}
```

**Project I want to use the method in:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestLibary.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    TestLiabry.TestLiabry();
}
```

**I added the library in the linker like this:**
*Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> C:\Users\jorda\Downloads\TestLiabry*

It pops out this error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB6006 "link.exe" exited with code 1104.   Project1    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 1010

And this lnk error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Users\jorda\Downloads\TestLiabry.obj'  Project1    C:\Users\jorda\Downloads\Project1\LINK  1

Comment: Go into more detail. What do you mean by "the project still does not recognise the library"? What do you see?

Comment: Thought that's how you use a library method. I tried just TestLiabry(); but that gave the error:                                                                                                           
 Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB6006 "link.exe" exited with code 1104. Project1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 1010

Comment: @Madmitten As from what you shown the code in `main()` should be just `TestLia();brys()` or `::TestLiabrys();`, what's your specific problem?

Comment: I get a linker error when i try to run the project. I think it might have something to do with the path I put into the Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> C:\Users\jorda\Downloads\TestLiabry

Comment: _What_ link error? Post the whole thing.... Pretend we cannot see your computer screen from here.

Comment: i did post the error its in the question no? LNK1104 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be an error in my linking of the path to the library where I didn't include the library .lib. Only include the path and not the path and lib file in the directory.